# Printing value of iterator in dynamic div

Tags: html, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I have created a dynamic div which is rendered 19 times. I want to print the ID of iterator (i) in inner html dynamic Div. Can anyone please help me. Below is my code

```js
var d1 = document.getElementById("div1");
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  d1.innerHTML += '<div class="box">Print i here</div>';
}
```

```html
<h2>My Loop Printing Divs</h2>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variable directly like:

```js
var d1 = document.getElementById("div1");
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  d1.innerHTML += '<div class="box">Print ' + i + ' here</div>';
}
```

```html
<h2>My Loop Printing Divs</h2>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can used this way `string ${js code} string`

```js
var d1 = document.getElementById("div1");
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  d1.innerHTML += `<div class="box">Print ${i} here</div>`;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Loop Printing Divs</h2>
<div id="div1"></div>
```